# Will my game restart if I join a friend's game?

Tags: borderlands-2

I am further in Borderlands 2 than my friend and I was wondering if I join his game, will it make me restart the missions I have already completed? Or affect my storyline in any way?

Answer (score 6):

No, you will not restart any missions; you just won't get any additional credit for re-completing them. Once he gets to a mission you haven't completed, you'll each get credit for it.

Comment: I'm unsure what happens if you try to join the game of a player who's ahead of you, however.

Comment: If you join a game ahead of yours, you will not get credit for the quests the other person has completed, however if you do finish quests that you have not yet completed in your own game you will get credit for it, and when you go back your game you will have the option to "fast forward" your game to the point where you left off in the other game. It may treat story quests a little differently if you skip a major story quest though.

Comment: @onewho - that's what I'm wondering. I'd be surprised if you were able to skip a story quest, though I suppose it's possible.

Comment: If you are on story quest 3, and you join a friend's game on story quest 8 and then play up through quest 10, when you rejoin your game you will continue with story quest 3.  When you finish 7 (or possibly when you receive quest 8) it will give you the option to skip forward.  At that point the world will fast forward to quest 10, exactly as if you had played it in your own game.